# Cd to a network share as administrator

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, network-shares

I opened Powershell Prompt and the following works:

```
cd "\\serverName\sharedFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2"
```

Now I want to do the same but in the Powershell Prompt opened with administrator rule. I tried the same

```
cd "\\serverName\sharedFolder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2"
```

but I got that "Cannot find path ... beacuse it doesn't exists". What is the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMB shares not found on Windows 10 laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1371926/smb-shares-not-found-on-windows-10-laptop)

Comment: Not exactly. I used now `pushd "..."` and an in my network drive but when I want to go deeper then I got an error. When I type `get-childitem` I have no folders

Comment: Check you permissions. Remember there are two: File/folder permissions and share permissions.