# Powershell Get-ChildItem do not show subfolders

Tags: powershell

I used `pushd \\network\drive\path` to move into this drive in powershell. Then I used `Get-ChildItem` to check to which folders I can move from here. Unfortunately the results of this command is empty, while there is a lot of folders on my drive. What is the reason? I ran Powershell as administrator, without administrator rule there is no problem

Comment: You need to provide way more information than that. Explain the differences. Which PS version are you using? Are you dealing with hidden folders where `-Force` is necessary?

Comment: is that your gci call verbatim? if you run `pwd` are you actually in the directory you think you are?

Comment: [1] the `pushd` command DOES NOT change your filesystem location. all it does is `adds ("pushes") the current location onto a location stack`. ///// [2] the correct "change dir" command is `Set-Location`. ///// [3] you really otta always use the `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameters with `Get-ChildItem` ... it is far safer AND easier to debug.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey pushd should work. Powershell is perfectly capable of. An empty dir means lack of permissions to view content but not to navigate there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMB shares not found on Windows 10 laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1371926/smb-shares-not-found-on-windows-10-laptop)

Comment: @LPChip - that is truly freaky. the docs say that it ONLY puts the path on the stack and that you need `popd` to change location. thank you for pointing out the bug in the docs! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey dunno which docs you refer to. This is what I learned: pushd puts the path on the stack and changes directory to it, storing where it came from. popd removes it from the stack restoring the directory to where it was before pushd was. Calling pushd multiple times will require the same amount of popd as it traverses back the stack. popd is basically an undo.

Comment: @LPChip - my local version of help doesn't mention that ... but the online version _does_. i need to update help ... so i'm off to get that done. **_thank you for pushing me to do that._** [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because your administrator user lacks the privileges to view the content of the folder on this network share.

This is explained by the simple reason that it works without administrator, but not while using powershell as administrator.

I have confirmed this by making an alteration to one of my network shares. My user has rights but the user Administrator does not. I can view it the folder using pushd and dir as normal user, but not as admin. (and yes, dir is an alias for get-childitem)